# Best way for executing a callback when you fade elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise, fadein

Is there any difference between the following code snippets?

The usual way to create a `fadeIn` animation:

```
$( "#element" ).fadeIn(function() {
    // do something
});
```

As of jQuery 1.6:

```
$( "#element" ).fadeIn().promise().done(function() {
    // do something
});
```

From what I can understand reading the documentation:

- In the first example, the callback is called once per matched element.
- In the second example, the doneCallback is called when all matching elements have completed their animations.

So, supposing that your callback function is the same for all your elements, it is always preferable to use the code of the second example?

Comment: FYI, there's also a `when` [method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) which works as your second example:  
$.when($( "#element" ).fadeIn()).done(function() {});

Answer (score 1):

> So, supposing that your callback function is the same for all your
>   elements, it is always preferable to use the code of the second
>   example?

No, they behave differently. Your choice depends on your desired behavior.

- In the first case, the callback is called multiple times. One per each element **immediately after an element is faded in**.
- In the second case, the callback is called only once.

Comment: Yes, see my description. I didn't say something different.

Comment: @gmuser: you were asking `it is always preferable to use the code of the second example?`. My answer is No

Comment: Ok, understood. So I do believe that if for example, you want to `fadeIn` the elements and then `fadeOut` all of them, the second method is a better choice.